# How to print multilple words in c++

Tags: c++

I can get the file to save right but I can't seem to get multiple words to write to .txt, like if I type "Hi purple" it just writes "Hi", here is code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color F0");
    string name0;        
    cout << "Please enter a file name, no spaces/special characters" << endl;
    cin >> name0;
    name0 = name0+".txt";
    system("cls");
    cout << "            FISHSOFT" << endl;
    cout << "The best text editor in the world" << endl << endl;
    string text;
    cin >> text;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (name0.c_str() , ios::out | ios::trunc);
    myfile << text;
    myfile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read an entire line of input including spaces.

Answer (score 2):

std::cin is able to get several parameters at once.

That mean you may write:

```
std::cin >> name0 >> name1 >> name2;
// input: a1 a2 a3
// make: name0: a1, name1: a2, name3:a3
```

By default, the space is the separator between parameters.

To avoid this behavior, you could use getLine:

```
std::getline(std::cin, name0);
```

Comment: It's `std::getline`, with a lower-case L. And the function does not return a string, but takes a string reference.

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> text;` will read one whitespace delimited token from the input stream. One word in == one word out.

`std::getline(cin, text);` will read a whole line. Reading more than that is tricky, but typically a loop around multiple calls to getline.

Suggestion: Save yourself time and fire up your IDE's debugger to see what's happening in your code before posting a question. Almost always faster, and if not, you can make much better, tighter-focused questions.

Comment: I sympathise with the advice to use a debugger, but how would it have helped in this particular case?

Comment: read contents of text after cin, see that it's not all of what was typed. Quickly eliminates output error from contention and OP might make the connection between whitespace and where cin stopped reading the input. After that, a quick perusal of the cin documentation, or a search for "why does cin only read one word?" should answer the question. For me google returns two useful SO hits right at the top.

Comment: Well, if I read the question correctly, the OP does correctly realise that only one word ends up in the `text` or `name0` strings but cannot figure out why. In this case, reading documentation is more important than using the debugger.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The way I read it is the OP can't get why it only wrote one word and doesn't realize that it only read one.

Comment: Actually, when I do this, it doesn't do anything, just skips the line

Comment: @RaberSaber  `cin >> name0;` way up at the top left a trailing linefeed in the stream. You type in the file name and hit enter. cin takes the file name and leaves the enter in the stream in case you want it later. getline grabs everything up to the next enter, unfortunately that enter comes immediately. After you read in the name, put in the following line to get rid of the rest of the crap on that line and the enter: `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` Reads to the end of the line or a few bajillion characters, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to get the string with spaces and special character.

1. cin.getline(name);
2. gets(name);

Hope this will serve your purpose.